# Ajax sending variable value to MVC controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send a value from jQuery using ajax call and fetch the value in the controller. Below is what I am trying, but the value of A is always null. Can someone help me where I am going wrong.

```
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",       //The type of Method being used (GET, SET, POST, etc.)
                url: '/Controller1/Index',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                
                data: { A: "true" },           //Your data to pass to your Controller action
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(response.responseText);                
                    alert("Done!");
                }
            });
```

C# code

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ActionName("Index")]
 public ActionResult IndexPost(FilterRule queryBuilder, BootstrapTableQueryType bootstrapTable, string A)
 {
     string B = A;
 }
```

Comment: For starters, since you've specified `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, then you'll need `data: JSON.stringify({ A: "true" })`.

Comment: Or just delete `contentType` so it uses the default. but why does your method contain paramaters for `FilterRule` and `BootstrapTableQueryType` when you never send data related to them?

Comment: I am facing another problem. I am getting the value of string A from the Ajax call. But, the Index is triggered twice. When it triggers first time, queryBuilder values are null and String A has value. When it triggers second time, queryBuilder values are present and String A is null. Anyone has any insights why the Index could be called twice. Please suggest.

Comment: To Stephen Muecke - I am sending data related to FilterRule and BootstrapTableQueryType. Now, that is where I am having trouble.